# Are there examples of software that use a dark colour scheme?

Tags: color, software-recommendation, interface-design

A client told me they want something with more a design software feel rather than web 2.0 feel, particularly something with a dark colour scheme. So now I am looking for some examples to show to him. I do not use many different types of software, so I am just looking for something that looks nice so i can understand what he likes or doesn't like.

The only one I've thought of is the dark colour in Adobe Bridge, but I was wondering if there is other software that tends to be on the dark grey side? Please include a screenshot of the software example.

The most interesting one that I found is [Final Cut Pro Server](http://www.creativeobserver.com/img/6130_apple_final_cut_server_lg.jpg). I would appreciate if you have some other software designs to suggest. I am focusing on the visual, not so much the UI, as it is a matter of taste not functionality.

Comment: What do you mean with "dark side"? Colour scheme? It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. Could you be more specific? What actually is the question you want answers to? (or should this be flagged as community wiki?)

Comment: My fault, I was hurrying writing, and I didn't actually wrote properly my thoughts. I edited everything again, I hope that is more clear.

Comment: So do you just want examples of software that use a dark theme?

Comment: @people that vote down or to close: please explain why you do not think that is a good question, or how to make it a good question, so I can avoid to make something not related. @Jaips: yes Looking for designs on dark themes

Comment: i think the basis of the question is fine, but just needs to be rewritten more simply for clarity. The headline should be in the form of a question and be centred around colourschemes.

Comment: I think you need to go back and ask your client this question. They know what they want. We don't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adobe Lightroom (and many of Adobe's other apps) effectively use a dark color scheme:
[image]

More screenshots: http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/

Answer (score 8):

**[Blender](http://www.blender.org/features-gallery/features/)**

[image]

Comment: Similar to this - Cinema 4D

Comment: ZBrush as well (3D sculpting app).

Answer (score 6):

- Newer versions of [**Adobe's design apps**](http://www.adobe.com/products/creativesuite/design/)
- [**Microsoft Expression**](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/)
- [**Microsoft Visual Studio 2010**](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions) (sort of, the default theme is dark / light mix but not black and grays).

I'd also say to do a search for "dark colour scheme" web sites and look at the samples that are out there.  The web sites are a lot less overkill than installing a big software package just to look at the color scheme.

Comment: About the search: I had exactly the problem to look for something more software like, than web like. For this reason I am asking to the knowledge of the group, for example I never use photography software and I do not own any.

Comment: Just to note that Adobe Lightroom (in its latest incarnation it's) 'Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 3' is another one, but not included in Creative Suite. http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/

Comment: @e100: Thanks!  I did mean to add that one...

Answer (score 5):

*Sorry mis-understood the question the first time*.

New answer: There are quite a few examples of software using a dark theme, most of the ones already mentioned cover photo, video/animation.

But there are other examples too:

Most Autodesk design products use a dark theme by default. For example **AutoCAD**:

[image: AutoCAD for Mac screenshot]

**Microsoft office** has a dark theme (though its not the default).

[image: MS Word with black theme screenshot]

And **Steam** uses a dark theme based on the ['metro' design language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_Design_Language)

[image: Steam screenshot]

Dark theme's seem to be quite 'in' at the moment, many of these programs have only recieved a dark theme refresh in the last few releases. Personally i find it helps the visual hierarchy of the screen, allowing the main content - photo, video, drawing, ad's - to be more prominant while the UI sort of 'fades to the background'

Comment: Question appears to be asking for examples of software with a similar UI colourscheme/visual style, not similar functionality.

Comment: AND Final Cut Pro Server is mentioned in the question itself...

Comment: Hey how do change the word theme? I've never seen that before.

Comment: using office 2007 (i think it is similar for 2010): office-orb > [word] options > then under 'popular options' look for the color scheme drop-down box

Answer (score 4):

There's [pixelmator](http://www.pixelmator.com/), if that counts.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try Looking at Theme Forest (http://themeforest.net/)

http://themeforest.net/theme_previews/148819-javiero-creative-psd-template?index=9

or Adobe Flex has some good Interface

http://www.cornflex.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/saffron_preview.jpg

or Browse Interface Gallery (http://userinterfacegallery.com)

Comment: thx for the link but it has to be a software, not a website

Comment: I can see a pattern that Online Apps and Desktop Apps are becoming one in terms of design. You just asked for a color scheme, you can get it almost everywhere.

Comment: If you check the question I said "to a software design", and if you read the question it is exactly the difference that I am making because the client do not want a web design.

Comment: @Littlemad sorry, my bad. I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 2):

Snowtape for Mac has a dark theme:

http://www.vemedio.com/products/snowtape

Sorry, can't post image, new user, not enough rep.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu's unity is a good exemple of well integrated dark color scheme. http://unity.ubuntu.com/about/

Answer (score 0):

Apple Aperture too, as nearly every imaging / photo software, has a dark color GUI.

Answer (score 0):

GIMP has themes, and there's quite a few dark ones.

YouTube video explaining the process: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFBFXoohAdg

Answer (score 0):

Darktable, see https://www.darktable.org/about/screenshots/

Digikam, see https://www.digikam.org/

PhotoFlow, see https://photoflowblog.blogspot.de/2016/03/photoflow-version-026-released.html